# Linker error when trying to reference static library project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, static-libraries

I have two projects in my Visual Studio solution: A (static library .lib project) and B (project that uses A). I have referenced A in B by following the steps:

`right click B > properties > common properties > references > add new reference > select A from projects tab`

I have set the path for .h files using `additional include directories` option in `properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General`

Project A builds successfully when built separately. But on building project B, it show `unresolved external symbol` errors like follows:

```
Error   46  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewActiveTexture    c:\Users\student\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MCAProject\Narovatar\Narovatar\OGLDEV_Imported.lib(ogldev_texture.obj)   Narovatar
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewAttachShader c:\Users\student\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MCAProject\Narovatar\Narovatar\OGLDEV_Imported.lib(technique.obj)    Narovatar
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewBindBuffer   c:\Users\student\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MCAProject\Narovatar\Narovatar\ogl_mesh.obj  Narovatar
Error   13  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewBufferData   c:\Users\student\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MCAProject\Narovatar\Narovatar\ogl_mesh.obj  Narovatar
```

What could I have left? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click `properties -> linker -> general ->additional library directories-> browse for your lib file directory`.

Right click `properties -> linker -> general ->input-> write your lib file name`.

Do not forget to make them **both** *MT* or **both** *MD* like following:

`properties -> C/C++ -> Code generation -> Runtime-library-> change them both to be the same`

Comment: @Nickal edited for more information see this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this in modern visual studio unless its a 3rd party .lib that you didn't compile as part of the sln

Comment: I made **both** MT but doesn't work. Actually, its finding the .lib file (see OGLDEV_Imported.lib in the above given error) but the errors seem to be from inside the library.

Comment: The project B I am talking about is `Narovatar` and project A is `OGLDEV_Imported` that produces `OGLDEV_Imported.lib`

Comment: This did the job. I think that it is quite annoying that this is not done automatically by Visual Studio when adding a reference to a static library project within the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my answer myself, of course with the help of help from all those who responded. Actually, the project A (.lib project) had all the header files and implementations in the same folder which I was referencing in the project B. So, when all the implementations were already available, I didn't have to link my the .dll output of project A in project B, but just had to refer it.

Another problem was that I had not linked (in project B) the libraries that were required for building project A. Now, its up and running...